# Missing sentinel at method dispatch although nil is present in argument list

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, compiler-warnings, sentinel

I want to create a `UIActionSheet` but I always get a warning about a "missing sentinel":

> /Users/....mm:136:173: warning: missing sentinel in method dispatch [-Wsentinel]

```
UIActionSheet* adsl_action_sheet = [[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                                delegate:(id<UIActionSheetDelegate>)self 
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:[dsd_string_localizer ms_get_localized_system_string:@"Cancel"] 
                                                  destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                                                       otherButtonTitles:[dsd_string_localizer ms_get_localized_system_string:@"Logoff"], [dsd_string_localizer ms_get_localized_system_string:@"Disconnect"], nil] autorelease];
```

I really can't see anything wrong... maybe I'm just blind.

The file containing this code is an Objective-C++ file.

I also noticed that it is showing these "Sentinel Warnings" at every place which needs such a sentinel.

Comment: Show the complete compiler warning message.

Comment: @trojanfoe i added the warning from the log, hope thats what you wanted

Comment: It looks like the compiler doesn't see that last `nil`.  What happens if you change it to `(NSString *)nil`?

Comment: (NSString*)nil worked wonders, warning disappeared. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast that final "sentinel" `nil` to the correct type, using:

```
... , (NSString *)nil] autorelease];
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

<strike>However, I am not certain *why* the compiler requires this cast.</strike>

I *believe* this is necessary when compiling with `-Wstrict-null-sentinel` (waiting for confirmation from OP).

Comment: can you explain why is the cast necessary?

Comment: @tiguero No I cannot, but I haven't looked extensively.

Comment: accepted, would be interesting to know why you have to cast.

Comment: @ManuelWa Are you compiling with the flag `-Wstrict-null-sentinel`?

Comment: @trojanfoe will check that on friday, have school tomorrow and i am at work again on friday

Comment: @trojanfoe i'm working with xcode5 and couldn't find where this flag is specifically set. didn't work much with compilers yet :/

Answer (score 1):

From the compiler output i believe that you are not putting a `nil` correctly at the end of the variadic method call.